# Delete all duplicated elements in a vector in Julia 1.1

Tags: julia

I am trying to write a code which deletes all repeated elements in a Vector. How do I do this?

I already tried using `unique` and `union` but they both delete all the repeated items but 1. I want all to be deleted.

For example: let `x = [1,2,3,4,1,6,2]`. Using `union` or `unique` returns `[1,2,3,4,6]`. What I want as my result is `[3,4,6]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are lots of ways to go about this. One approach that is fairly straightforward and probably reasonably fast is to use `countmap` from `StatsBase`:

```
using StatsBase
function f1(x)
    d = countmap(x)
    return [ key for (key, val) in d if val == 1 ]
end
```

or as a one-liner:

```
[ key for (key, val) in countmap(x) if val == 1 ]
```

`countmap` creates a dictionary mapping each unique value from `x` to the number of times it occurs in `x`. The solution can then be easily found by extracting every `key` from the dictionary that maps to `val` of `1`, ie all elements of `x` that occur precisely once.

It might be faster in some situations to use `sort!(x)` and then construct an index for the elements of the sorted `x` that only occur once, but this will be messier to code, and also the output will be in sorted order, which you may not want. The `countmap` method preserves the original ordering.